# Tell ViewController to move a second image after the first one is dragged

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have created a custom UIImageView class called DragImageView that allows an image to be dragged on the screen with animations for the first and last touches.  In my ViewController, I have several different images with this class.  What I am trying to do is once the first image is dragged and released, a second image will translate to the initial starting point of the first image.  The second image can be be dragged and once it is released, a third image translates to the same starting point and so on.  Currently, after I drag an image, I have to re-touch the screen for the next image to translate.  I would like for it to automatically translate after the user completes the drag.  Any help/suggestions would be awesome.

// In DragImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DragImageView : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint startLocation;
    CGPoint endLocation;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL complete; // Hoping this will tell ViewController to move next image

@end
```

// In DragImageView.m

```
#import "DragImageView.h"

@implementation DragImageView

@synthesize complete;

- (id) initWithImage: (UIImage *) anImage
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:anImage])
        self.complete = NO;
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    startLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:startLocation];
}

- (void)animateFirstTouchAtPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint{
#define GROW_FACTOR 1.4f
#define SHRINK_FACTOR 1.0f
#define GROW_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 0.15

    NSValue *touchPointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge_retained void *)touchPointValue];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:GROW_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(growAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GROW_FACTOR, GROW_FACTOR);
    self.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)growAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

#define MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS 0.25

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION_SECONDS];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SHRINK_FACTOR, SHRINK_FACTOR);
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = pt;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    endLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    [self animateLastTouchAtPoint:endLocation];
    self.complete = YES;
}

- (void) animateLastTouchAtPoint: (CGPoint) touchPoint
{
    NSValue *lastTouchPointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge_retained void *)lastTouchPointValue];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

// In ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DragImageView.h"

@class DragImageView;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CGPoint startPoint;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DragImageView *baseball;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DragImageView *basketball;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DragImageView *soccerBall;

- (void) moveBasketball;
- (void) moveSoccerBall;

@end
```

// In ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize baseball, basketball, soccerBall;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.baseball.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    startPoint = CGPointMake(self.baseball.center.x, self.baseball.center.y);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) moveBasketball
{
    self.basketball.center = startPoint;
}

- (void) moveSoccerBall
{
    self.soccerBall.center = startPoint;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.baseball.complete == YES)
    {
        [self moveBasketball];
        self.basketball.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    if (self.baseball.complete == YES && self.basketball.complete == YES)
    {
        [self moveSoccerBall];
        self.soccerBall.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the new block based animations, which Apple has recommended ever since iOS 4. Those methods have a completion block, so you can start your next animation in there when the animate last touch ends.